# How can I add a schema to AWS Athena from a JSON schema file?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

So my situation is that I have about 120 million json files in S3 that I would like to query against using AWS Athena.  I also have a JSON schema file.  Is there a way I use the schema file to build the Athena table schema?  The schema is quite complex, to the point that creating the schema by hand is untenable.  It also seems ridiculous to scan all 120 million records with Glue when I already have access to the schema.

I've tried searching for answers to this question but I haven't been able to find anything that seemed quite relevant.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not create an external table once on Athena manually. It is a one time step.

Comment: Can you provide some idea of how you JSON schema file looks like, please? In general, you should be able to define databases and tables using [AWS Glue API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog.html). boto3 library provides nice top level API for such tasks.

Comment: the JSON has a lot of nested classes and stuff like that, that's why it's so complex.  It's complex enough that building a table by hand would be very time consuming.  I just don't understand why I can't give Athena a big pile of JSON files and a schema file and let it go to town.